# Jquery code explication

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie and I'm trying to make smooth scroll in my one page scroll website.
I found this code from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

```
$(function () {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It works perfectly, problem is that I don't understand it !
Could someone explain it for me ?

P.S. - I don't know if this is a valid question for stackoverflow, if it's not just tell me and I delete this post.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
//^^^^ by this code start on dcocument load
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
 //^^^^ set selector  (anchor tag) 
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') &&          location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
  // ^^^^check target length is exist in target hash coming if this exist then go in if othervise not
    $('html,body').animate({
     //^^^^ here html and body animate 
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
     //^^^^ get target scroll top position and move html,body scroll to this position
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Comment: thanks. but what the first if does and the hash.slice in target?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice